# Adding , to a number input box vue

Tags: vue.js

I have a vue page that allows the user to edit prices to their products, when they edit the product's price the input box shows `1234.00` and I was
wondering if there is a way to add a ',' in the necessary spots on a number for example `1,234.00` or `2,000,000.00`.

I know that the reason why the price shows up as `1234.00` is because when I save the data I remove the `,`.

Here is my vue file

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="row">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" :value="product.name">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" :value="product.description">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" :value="product.price">

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" @click="updateProduct">
                Update
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script type="text/javascript">

    export default {
        props: ['product'],

        data() {
            return {

            }
        },
        methods: {
            updateProduct(){
                axios.put('/api/products/update/'+this.product.id, {
                    name: this.product.name,
                    description: this.product.description,
                    price: this.product.price,
                }).then(response => {
                    console.log(response);
                })
            }
        },


        mounted() {
            
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has a built-in function for this.
If you’re sure the variable is always Number and never a “number String”, you can do:

```
product.price.toLocaleString()
```

If you want to be safe, do:

```
Number(product.price).toLocaleString()
```

Comment: Sorry for only getting back to you now, but when I try that, my price disappears from the page and I get this in my console `The specified value "2,000,000.00" cannot be parsed, or is out of range.` and `The specified value "NaN" cannot be parsed, or is out of range.`